# Sql Server Compact string encoding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

How to extort using utf8 for strings in SqlServer CE?

To save 'ą', 'ę' etc. language special characters?

@Edit:

I use EntityFramework and when db is mysqlserver data have special characters like 'ą', 'ę' but when I swtich to SqlServerCompact the data lost special chars.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server CE supports `nvarchar` and `ntext`, which are UTF-16. Basically: store your data as UTF-16 in an `nvarchar` column, and you'll be set. Conveniently, .NET is *also* mostly UTF-16 (the `char` and `string` types are implemented as UTF-16), so this works out just fine.

If you *absolutely must* use UTF-8, you'll have to use `varbinary` / `image`, which means you lose most of the useful features of a database. You'll be able to store and retrieve, but filtering and other operations are much harder.

When storing data, make sure you either use `N'foo'` syntax for literals, or ADO.NET parameters of `DbType.String` (`nvarchar`) / `DbType.StringFixedLength` (`nchar`), and **not** `DbType.AnsiString` (`varchar`) / `DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength` (`char`)